# Why is a union breaking the return type of my function

Tags: typescript

He is my function and its types:

```
export interface KeyValue<K, V> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
}

declare function transform<T, K extends keyof T>(input: T): Array<KeyValue<K, T[K]>>;


interface MyInterface {
    one?: string;
    two?: string;
    three?: string;
}

declare const myData: MyInterface | null;    
const foo = transform(myData)
```

This code returns a type of `KeyValue<never, never>[]`.

I tried using a conditional return type : `T extends null ? null : Array<KeyValue<K, T[K]>>` but issue is still the same.

Any idea why this is happening when I have a union ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgaWAE8A1TAGwFdgAefAGjhID44BvAKDm7gGtiAXAQDcXHgDcK1ISVEBfDhwAmwbOUxQ86SkmwwEEJHBhRMSAM7poAWxoAVRvjihUSJeb7EI6OHeYAKZDBKGCE7AEohAEEoUyI6YjIqWgZfAG18AF1mZlEOZFQMHDwAWSIASRQ0LFx2MW5DYAB%20IXMTZABzUR5jAHcIFrg2qE7unhgAC01m1vakLo4FZVV1TThsQza4ayIAEUwYTCEyysKavAAfOCRKcnI8jYt4Kwg4AF5jUwsrKGt-Hf2h3CHAA9CCegA9JpAA)

Comment: Because `MyInterface | null` has no keys. `null` has no keys, and the union of a type has the intersection of its keys (e.g., `keyof ({a: 0, b: 1} | {b: 2, c: 3})` is just `"b"`. So `K` is constrained `K` to `never`. Could you articulate why you expect something else and what this code is supposed to do? I don't see why `K` exists, since there's no inference site for it.  In any case I'm happy to write up an answer saying "`keyof (X | Y)` is generally equivalent to `(keyof X) & (keyof Y)` and `keyof null` is `never` so you get `never` everywhere", if that fully addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Potential Solution:

explicitly check the type of myData before passing it to the transform function. You can use a conditional type to handle the case when myData is null separately.

```
export interface KeyValue<K, V> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
}

declare function transform<T, K extends keyof T>(
    input: T | null
): T extends null ? null : Array<KeyValue<K, T[K]>>;

interface MyInterface {
    one?: string;
    two?: string;
    three?: string;
}

declare const myData: MyInterface | null;
const foo = transform(myData);
```